# Routing network data in app domains

Tags: c#, .net, networking, appdomain

I have an application that sits above multiple separate applications each running in their own app domains. There has a arisen a need for 2 different applications to make use of port 80 to serve some web traffic. Is there any way to capture network open requests in the parent domain and manage the network traffic to pass the data to each separate domain as necessary? Is their an alternative architecture that I should be considering?

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the opened request on the parent domain and wrap it with a class which inherits MarshalByRefObject. A reference to such class can be moved to another AppDomain easily.

Notice that you should wrap ANY class that is passed between AppDomains (method parameters, result returned, EventArgs, etc.).

For example:

```
class Connection : MarshalByRefObject
{
    event ReceivedDataEventHandler ReceivedData;

    void Send(byte[] b)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class ReceivedDataEventArgs : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public string Data { get; }
}

delegate void ReceivedDataEventHandler(object sender, ReceivedDataEventArgs e);
```

Comment: Too bad the eventhandler of the event will be executed in the child domain, so it will transfer the whole main object (that registered the event) to the child domain.

Comment: You're right, that was just an example to clarify that ANY object that might be transferred between the AppDomains should inherit MarshalByRefObject. It means that the registered class should also inherit MarshalByRefObject or being Serializable (a small helper class can be used for this target only). Another alternative is to register using static delegate, if the application design enables that.